# output more precise delayed messages with python/pyserial

Tags: python, serial-port, sleep, pyserial

I use `time.sleep(0.01..)` to get delays between `serial.write(buffer)`, like that:

```
while True: 
  s.write(command) 
  time.sleep(0.01)
```

This works fine, but if the sleep arg is less than about 0.015 sec, some messages appear without a delay on the external interface.

Is there a better solution to get more precise timing for python.

i use it to test embedded devices and its serial interfaces. I know i am working with python (and a operating system), so no real time can be reached. But this method is very easy and flexible .. so i will improve it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind spinning/burning a bit of CPU instead of sleeping you can take advantage of the (more or less precise) usec resolution of the `time.time()` results, something along these lines:

```
import time

def usec_sleep(sleep_time_in_usec):

    start_time = time.time() * 1000000
    end_sleep = start_time + sleep_time_in_usec

    # regular sleep until ~20 msec before end_sleep
    sleep_time_minus_20_msec = end_sleep - start_time - 20000
    if sleep_time_minus_20_msec > 0:
        time.sleep(sleep_time_minus_20_msec/1000000)

    # spinning (for better precision) for the last up to ~20 msec
    while time.time() * 1000000 < end_sleep:
        pass
```

Comment: Thank you, i will check it this week.

Comment: it is nearly the same as in my current approach. i think it depence more or less on the interface/os/driver layer. the puffer will be written in precise intervalls, but the interface is serviced less often.